Arduino serial port communication with Python
I use an Arduino UNO r3 via USB port attached to a PC running WIN 10 and Python. The Arduino converts the status of an attached analog switch (status open or closed) to binary code to the Python script. Everything works fine, however after some time (hours or even days) the python script gets no data anymore from the Arduino. The Arduino sketch looks like this:
#include <avr/wdt.h>  // Include watchdog library

#define ButtonPIN 8
#define LED 13

bool oldState;

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(115200);
 pinMode(ButtonPIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
 pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
 bool state = digitalRead(ButtonPIN);
 sendMessage(state);
 oldState = state;
 Serial.println("Setup complete");
 delay(1000);  // Ensure setup message is sent before entering the loop
 wdt_enable(WDTO_8S);  // Enable watchdog timer with an 8-second timeout
}

void loop() {
wdt_reset();  // Reset the watchdog timer

bool state = digitalRead(ButtonPIN);
 if (oldState != state) {
  digitalWrite(LED, state);
  sendMessage(state);
  delay(500);  // Debounce delay
  oldState = state;
 }
}

void sendMessage(bool state) {
 Serial.write(0x01);
 Serial.write(0x29);
 Serial.write(state ? 0x01 : 0x00);
 Serial.write(0xEE);
 Serial.write('\n');
}

How can i debug this? In the serial monitor of the Arduino IDE things are looking correct, just in python the switch stops working at some point. I already checked hardware connections, OS sleep modus, bios setting for USB ports, etc.
I can also trigger the failure by toggling the hardware switch many, many times realy fast. The adurino seems to stop all communication. If i press the hardware reset button on he board all is back to normal.

No, the second one became male functioning as well with your code suggestion, but i was able to save it. The real problem was noise from the switch which i filtered with two 100mF conducters between pin 8 and GND and GND and VCC. By simulating the switch with a script you will create no noise. But noise can result in corrupted code like in my case.

I have reproduced your setup on an Arduino Uno running your code, and am running the code below in Python on Windows 10:
import serial

ser = serial.Serial("COM13", 115200)

byte_count = 0

while True:
    bytes_in = ser.read()
    byte_count += len(bytes_in)
    print(f"{bytes_in.hex().upper()}", end=' ')
    if byte_count >= 20 or bytes_in[0] == 0x0A:
        byte_count = 0
        print()

And everything runs as expected. So to simulate multiple hits on the button I replaced your if (oldState != state) with if (true), and changed the delay from 500ms to 5ms to get a large number of button presses in rapid succession. It has clocked up more than 65,000 strings sent, with no issues at all.
Perhaps you could test your setup with my Python code. Hopefully it will run without a problem, which should make it easy to modify your Python code accordingly. But if the fault persists then it is likely to be a Windows issue.

Thank you very much. I will try and give a response asap.

I get the hex values and it is just running fine. Problem is now that the Arduino does not react anymore to the switch after 10 or more hours. It does not matter if the switch is actually toggled or not.

I would comment out the two lines that deal with the watchdog timer (just to take them out of the equation).  Then I would put code into your main loop to flash the LED each time around the loop (say 100ms on 100ms off). You can then monitor this to see if the flashing stops at the point when your button becomes unresponsive. This will also have the advantage that it puts a delay into the main loop. At the moment you have none, and I find that this can sometimes cause issues.

yes the button stops flashing pretty quickly (20 sec) and the LED stays on. Just needed a few toggles. But what does that tell me?

Can you confirm that you have taken out all the watchdog stuff? Now try the same thing but without the Python code running. Does it still stop flashing after 20 seconds?

The previous change made my Arduino not working any more, does not show up on the ports anymore, so i can nor preceed, sorry.

Does your Arduino still work with a simple blink program?

I am sorry i can not recover the Arduino anymore and need to order a new one.

Maybe that was the problem all along: a faulty Arduino - though it is very rare.
